# Github avatar set in my own project profile picture

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, github-api

I create one of my own project which is DevConnector in React. This is a MERN stack project. In this profile picture of the user set on gravatar based email address. Now I have to set a GitHub profile picture as a user profile picture. One of my friends suggests me to use Github API ("https://api.github.com/users/${username}") and get avatar_url instead of gravatar.url.

Now the question is how to use this API in my project. 
**Here is my GitHub link:** https://github.com/urjit2498/DevConnector
Please check this repo and give me some solution to how to use it in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an undocumented trick with how avatars are created that you could try:

- find your GitHub User ID - it' in the response from `https://api.github.com/users/{username}`
- test the URL in a browser - `https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/{id}`
- if that returns the avatar you expect, you can use that in your project

The `avatar_url` is the canonical value here and may change down the track, but that might help achieve what you're trying to do today.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a small addition to the comment of @Brendan Forster.
When you check this URL : `https://github.com/[YOUR_USERNAME].png` you will see that you are redirected to the following url: `https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/[YOUR_ID]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).